# Cisco route HTTP / HTTPS to proxy server

Tags: cisco, proxy, http, https

Given a Cisco router, is it possible to route all HTTP and HTTPS traffic to a proxy server for filtering, and allow the proxy server to send the filtered traffic back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. The feature you are looking for is named WCCP. Here is an Example with a Squid Proxy: http://www.crypt.gen.nz/papers/cisco_squid_wccp.html

Comment: Assuming the proxy server supports WCCP, and it fits with the network design. Another option might be PFR: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps8787/products_ios_protocol_option_home.html